# Move constructor not being called by std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the following code, why is the move constructor not called by the vector implementation if there is a copy constructor? I know it can call the move constructor since it does if there is no copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Cls1 {
public:
    Cls1() { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; } // default constructor
    Cls1(Cls1&&) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; } // move constructor
};

class Cls2 {
public:
    Cls2() { std::cout << "default ctor\n"; } // default constructor
    Cls2(Cls2 const&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; } // copy constructor
    Cls2(Cls2&&) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; } // move constructor
};

template<typename T>
void test(T t1) {
    std::vector<T> v;
    std::cout << "First push:\n";
    v.push_back(std::move(t1));
    std::cout << "\nSecond push:\n";
    v.push_back(std::move(t1));
    std::cout << "\nThird push:\n";
    v.push_back(std::move(t1));
    std::cout << "\nresize:\n";
    v.reserve(100);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Cls1 - no copy constructor\n";
    Cls1 a;
    test(std::move(a));

    std::cout << "Cls1 - with copy constructor\n";
    Cls2 b;
    test(std::move(b));

    return 0;
}
```

You can see this here: http://cpp.sh/7wlo

The output I am getting for recent versions of both clang and gcc (using mingw) as well as whatever compiler is at the site linked above show that for `Cls2` the vector uses the copy constructor whenever it has to resize it's internal buffer and so misses an opportunity to optimize to a move. This is true for all levels of optimization.

Here is a sample output from running the above code. I noted the "wrong" lines:

```
Cls1 - no copy constructor
default ctor
move ctor
First push:
move ctor

Second push:
move ctor
move ctor

Third push:
move ctor
move ctor
move ctor

resize:
move ctor
move ctor
move ctor


Cls1 - with copy constructor
default ctor
move ctor
First push:
move ctor

Second push:
move ctor
copy ctor    <--

Third push:
move ctor
copy ctor    <--
copy ctor    <--

resize:
copy ctor    <--
copy ctor    <--
copy ctor    <--
```

**NOTE:** VS2015 actually seems to get this right.

Comment: Make it `noexcept`.

Comment: @ildjarn Make what `noexcept`?

Comment: The move constructor.

Comment: Is it even legal to ``std::move`` the same instance more than once?

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks. But then why can it call the copy constructor that is not `noexcept`? And how can it call the move constructor if there is no copy constructor?

Comment: @baruch : `vector` prefers the move constructor if it is noexcept, or the copy constructor otherwise; if there is no copy constructor then the move constructor will be used regardless.

Comment: @BitTickler Yes. The moved object is perfectly valid as an object, just not it's internal state. So you can use it in any way that does not access it's state